# Center a div vertically

Tags: javascript, css, margins

I have to center a div vertically, with only a margin above and below.

So I made it generate the margin with JavaScript, like this.

```
var xLength = ((document.getElementById("outerdiv").offsetHeight)+"px");

xLength = (xLength - 222); //222 is the Length of the to be centered div

xMargin = (xLength / 2); //because of the 2 margins
xMargin = (xMargin());

document.getElementById(innerdiv).style.marginTop = xMargin;
document.getElementById(innerdiv).style.marginBottom = xMargin;
```

Please help, can't get it to work, any ideas?

**Here is the CSS of outer and inner div:**

```
#outerdiv {   
    min-height:302px;
    width:58px;
    margin-left:640px;
    z-index:2;
    float:right;
    margin-right:228px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
}

#innerdiv {
    height:222px;
    width:58px;
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id='outerdiv'>
  <div id='innerdiv'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make an example of your current code (inluding html) on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: There are quite a few problems with that code..

Comment: You should post your entire code, otherwise we cannot really help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your element's parent doesn't have a defined height itself.

---

With respect to your JavaScript, one problem is this line, which makes no sense at all and should be removed:

```
xMargin = (xMargin());
```

You should also add 'px' to the values you are setting, and put quotes around the ID, like this:

```
document.getElementById('innerdiv').style.marginTop = xMargin + 'px';
document.getElementById('innerdiv').style.marginBottom = xMargin + 'px';
```

Comment: It does, like this `min-height:302px;`

Comment: Please post a link to a live example, with complete HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thank you, i am learning javascript, so sorry about the messy code

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = checkAvailableHeight;

window.onresize = checkAvailableHeight;

function checkAvailableHeight(){
    var yourDiv = document.getElementById("yourDiv");
    yourDiv.style.marginTop = ((window.innerHeight - yourDivHeight) / 2) + "px";
}
```

Comment: That is actually a pretty good solution, but i already solved it 5 months ago, thanks anyway.